# Re-UV with SmartUV after scaling UV island

Tags: uv

I have used SmartUV to unwrap my model (a dog cabine) in Blender. It works perfectly fine.

However, the "interior" of the dog cabine occupies a large area of the UVs. 
I don't want them to take up so much space as the interior will have very little color details. A square of 24x25 pixels would do.

When I scale the islands manually, I would have to scale each other part of the UV as well.

Is there perhaps a function that would re-sort / scale the other UVs (which I have not scaled down manually) according to my changes?

I hope it's clear what I want:

I want to tell Blender that the interior should not occupy so much space, but it should still use SmartUV (which is such an amazing time saver for me).

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: If you have already interior unwrapped like what I assume is done on the screenshot then select UV islands corresponding to interior and move those islands away on UV map, then scale them down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could:

- Select everything except the interior, then <kbd>U</kbd> *Smart UV Project*.
- Select the interior and again <kbd>U</kbd> *Smart UV Project*.
- Scale down and move this second unwrap where you want, or even, if you don't want to manage 2 UVs overlaying, give it a second material (with the same *Image Texture*).
- Note that you could use *Vertex Groups* to facilitate the selections.
- Also, in the *UV/Image Editor*, enable *Keep UV And Edit Mode Mesh Selection In Synch* so that you can see both the 2 UVs.

[image]

Comment: Oh man, you are a genius!!!!!!!!!! Exactely what I wanted. Thank you sooooooooooo much!!!!